# cursor does not exist in postgreSQL stored procedure

Tags: postgresql

here is my stored proc in PostgreSQL version 15:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE customer_select(OUT customers REFCURSOR)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    OPEN customers FOR
    SELECT * FROM public.customers;
END;
$$;
```

and here I am trying to call the proc

```
CALL customer_select('customer_cursor');
FETCH ALL FROM customer_cursor;
```

But I am getting an error

```
ERROR:  cursor "customer_cursor" does not exist
```

How do I get this to work? thanks

Comment: you need in your case declare the cursor seee https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close, I think the main issue is that you're using an `OUT` parameter rather than an `INOUT` parameter.

What you currently have returns something like:

```
<unnamed portal 13>
```

Meaning you'd have to do `fetch all from "<unnamed portal 13>";`

Eg: you aren't assigning it a name and a auto-generated name is being assigned instead. You could find this from a catalog (`pg_cursors`) table, but it's better to explicitly name it.

If you change the parameter to be `customers INOUT REFCURSOR` then you get something like:

```
call customer_select('my_cursor');

> my_cursor
```

Meaning you can do:

```
begin;
call customer_select('my_cursor');
fetch all from my_cursor;
commit
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE public.customers AS select 1 as id, 'John Doe' as name;
```

Short story long, there's no problem with an `OUT REFCURSOR` parameter, the problem is with plain SQL offering no way of holding onto the resulting cursor. In PL/pgSQL [`CALL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-CALLING-PROCEDURE) works a bit differently, so it's not an issue:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE customer_select(OUT customers REFCURSOR) AS $p$
BEGIN OPEN customers FOR SELECT * FROM public.customers; 
END $p$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DO $p$
DECLARE customer_cursor refcursor;
        customer_record record;
BEGIN CALL customer_select(customer_cursor);
      FETCH NEXT FROM customer_cursor INTO customer_record;
      CREATE TABLE fetched AS SELECT customer_record.id, customer_record.name;
END $p$;

SELECT * FROM fetched;
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe |

PL/pgSQL `CALL` accepts a variable as an `OUT` parameter in order to overwrite it. Plain SQL [`CALL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-OUTPUT-PARAMETERS-PROC) requires that you provide an argument of the right type (or coercible to the right type) only to match the signature; it doesn't do anything with it. If you wanted it to affect the routine, you'd make it an `IN` or `INOUT`. As a consequence, you could've just as well give it a `null`, which is the convention.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE customer_select(OUT customers REFCURSOR) AS $p$
BEGIN OPEN customers FOR SELECT * FROM public.customers;
END $p$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CALL customer_select(null);
```

Thing is, [*Internally, a `refcursor` value is simply the string name of the portal containing the active query for the cursor.*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-USING) So giving it a `null` (or making it ignore the value because it's an `OUT` parameter) leaves the cursor without a name, forcing PostgreSQL to use a default name similar to how unnamed columns in a `select` are named `?column?` by default.

| customers |
| --- |
| <unnamed portal 2> |

It *is* available in [`pg_cursors`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-cursors.html) but there's no way to dynamically use it in plain SQL - you can't give `fetch` a subquery that returns the name. The operator (you manually or the app using the client) can only read it from the result of the `CALL` (or look it up) and feed it back into `FETCH`.

```sql
FETCH ALL FROM "<unnamed portal 2>";
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe |

You can't override that default name either, because `OUT` parameters don't accept defaults:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE customer_select(OUT customers REFCURSOR default 'customer_cursor') AS $p$
BEGIN OPEN customers FOR SELECT * FROM public.customers;
END $p$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

> ```
> ERROR:  only input parameters can have default values
> ```

`INOUT` of course solves the problem because while you're not really getting the cursor back, you can reference it by the name you gave it (without having the procedure quietly discard it), removing the need for a name lookup/rewrite.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE customer_select(INOUT customers REFCURSOR) AS $p$
BEGIN OPEN customers FOR SELECT * FROM public.customers;
END $p$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CALL customer_select('customer_cursor');
FETCH ALL FROM "customer_cursor";
```

| customers |
| --- |
| customer_cursor |

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe |

[Demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/54goyoaQ)

Answer (score -1):

Because the cursor was not declared before attempting to fetch from it in your PostgreSQL stored method, the error `cursor 'customer_cursor' does not exist` appears. Explicitly declaring the cursor before using the stored method will help you fix this problem. The cursor can be declared and linked to the output of the `customer_select` stored procedure using the `DECLARE` command. Once the stored procedure has been called, the result will be linked to the declared cursor even if the cursor name is not specified. Finally, it is possible to retrieve data from the cursor without mentioning its name in the `FETCH` statement. With this revised method, you may access the data as intended while also ensuring that the cursor is correctly specified and that the error is removed.